# How to dynamically limit time range?

Tags: search, date-range, splunk

I have two sourcetypes:

`A` defines the period of activities:

> _time, entity, start_time, end_time, activity, ...

`B` defines the 2D position of the entities:

> _time, entity, x, y, ....

Now I tried to extract only those rows of all the entities in B that is within the periods defined in A, how can I do that? It seems I can't make a comparison with the command 'join' for time?

Comment: What is the meaning of the _time field in A in relation to start_time and end_time?  What is the meaning of the _time field in B?  Do you expect many rows in A and/or B with the same value of entity?

Comment: _time in A is actually insignificant here, I put it here just because spunk always have this field. Important thing is how to compare _time in B to start time and end time in A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, [join](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/Join) won't be much help here.  I've found that the splunk way to match up information in two indexes is to start with both indexes and manipulate the heterogeneous events as if they were a single index.

In this case, one approach uses [streamstats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/Streamstats) to produce events that are denormalized to include relevant activity fields on each position event.  First, make sure each event from index A considers start_time to be the `_time` field.  Then, use `streamstats` to fill each event with null `start_time`, `end_time`, or `activity` fields (which should be coming from index B) with the latest value for that `entity` that was non-null (which should be coming from index A).  Finally filter out any events where `_time` > `end_time`, which would be any position event that falls outside an activity window.

```
index=A OR index=B
| eval _time=coalesce(start_time, _time)
| streamstats latest(start_time) as activity_start_time, latest(end_time) as activity_end_time, latest(activity) as activity by entity
| where _time<=end_time
```

Keep in mind that this approach assumes that activities are neatly ordered, so that no activity overlaps another.  This would be a bit trickier if activities can overlap.

Another method I sometimes use is to use [transaction](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/Transaction) instead of `streamstats`.  This gives much more control over the logic around when one activity starts and ends, and results in a single event per activity with multi-valued fields for the position.  You'd want to start with a single "point" field for each position if you took this route.